# Tomcat server started but not hitting the URL from controller

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I developed a sample maven project(reference [link](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)). Finally, it was not
running as expected.

Here is the [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D7H4.png).

Below is the code :
**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Counter Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cleanTempDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.controller" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<h1>Welcome..!!!</h1>
<a href="/SampleProj/home.html">click</a>
<%-- <%request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.html").forward(request,  response);%> --%>
```

**home.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Maven + Spring MVC Web Project Example</h1>
</body>
```

**BaseController.java**

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

private static final String VIEW_INDEX = "home";

@RequestMapping(value = "home.html")
public String welcome(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome");

    // Spring uses InternalResourceViewResolver and return back index.jsp
    return VIEW_INDEX;

}
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sample.java</groupId>
<artifactId>SampleProj</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SampleProj Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Unit Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>SampleProj</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <!-- Eclipse project -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
                <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
            <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- For Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <path>/SampleProj</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

**Output:**
[welcome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88zoE.png).
 After click.,,
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK2xl.png)

I tried with all possible cases but no use at all.
But other projects from another eclipse version and another workspace(same tomcat version) are working fine. I tried the same project with out maven(Adding jars from build path), its working. For maven its not happened as expected. I think, pom file was interrupted the flow. Is there any need to change eclipse settings.?(There is no errors in Show View(Problems)). Suggest me..

Comment: 1)-check if your controller in packge com.mkyong.controller .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maven dependencies missing from deployment assembly. So add maven dependencies to your deployment assembly.

Project->Properties->Deployment assembly->Add->Java 
 Build Path Entries->Maven Dependencies.

After above procedure restart your tomcat server.